# Add date created stamp to seaborn visualization

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

Is there an easy way to add a date created timestamp to the bottom right corner of any seaborn plot? Or on a subplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless seaborn has a function to do this, the easiest way to do this would be.

First, use DateTime to get the current system date.

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
```

Then just use seaborns plot.fig.text to add the text in

```
import seaborn as sns
plot = <setup plot here>

plot.fig.text(X_cord,y_cord,today)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How do I determine the appropriate X_cord and y_cord? @SirAchesis

Comment: If I remember correctly the x and y cords are based on the values for the x and y axel.
For example, if you have a plot with the valus ranging from 0-10 on both the y and x axis, then setting the chords to (5,5) should place it in the the middle of the plot.
(0,0) would place it in the bottom left
(10,0) would place it in the bottom right.

You can use this logic to figure out the correct values for you own plot.